# How to replace an empty entry with zero in a delimited string

Tags: java

I have a `String` such as this, with the delimiter being ';':

```
 String line = ";;7.52;;;;;;2.89;3.05;2.48;";
```

How can I replace the empty entries within it with zero so it looks like this:

```
 ";0;7.52;0;0;0;0;0;2.89;3.05;2.48;"
```

Everything I've tried gives me an error.

I've tried:

```
line = line.replace(null, 0);
```

and

```
line = line.replace("", 0)
```

all which give me this or something similar:

> No signature of method: java.lang.String.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer) values: [, 0]

Comment: Please show your best good-faith attempt and the errors that you're receiving.

Comment: I've tried "line = line.replace(null, 0)" and "line = line.replace("", 0)" all which give me this or something similar: No signature of method: java.lang.String.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer) values: [, 0]

Comment: Please don't try to expand your question with comments on it.  Instead, [edit] your question to add any additional information.  SO isn't a chat board; all the information required to answer your question needs to be contained in the question itself.

Comment: `0` is an integer value, `"0"` is a string. Replace doesn't understand the intent of your string, that between `;;` is "something empty". Try and replace `";;"` with `";0;"` (which doesn't fill a first or last field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as follows:

```
public class Demo {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str=";;7.52;;;;;;2.89;3.05;2.48;";
        while(str.contains(";;"))
            str=str.replaceAll(";;", ";0;");            
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
;0;7.52;0;0;0;0;0;2.89;3.05;2.48;
```

Answer (score 3):

shortest one:

```
String line = ";;7.52;;;;;;2.89;3.05;2.48;";
String newLine = line.replace(";;", ";0;")
                     .replace(";;", ";0;")
                     .replace(";;", ";");
```

Comment: Its will produce wrong output, there should be 5 zeroes between 7.52 and 2.89.

Comment: @ShubhamSaraswat - you right.I fixed, but now it is not so short :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string into an character array, create a arraylist of characters and add each character into the arraylist. if a two adjacent characters are ; then add 0.
Then use `Streams` to convert the arraylist into a string.

```
        String s = ";;7.52;;;;;;2.89;3.05;2.48;";
        char arr[] = s.toCharArray();
        ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
            list.add(arr[i]);
            if ( arr[i]==';' && arr[i+1]==';') {
                list.add('0');
            }
        }
        String newStr = list.stream()
                            .map(String::valueOf)
                            .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Note: Don't forget to import `Collectors` (`import java.util.stream.Collectors;`).

Comment: Or just `String replaced = Arrays.stream(line.split(";"))
                    .map(e -> e.isEmpty()?"0":e).collect(Collectors.joining(";"));`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method:

```
    int countOf(String s, char c) {
        int ct, i, j;
        char _c;

        for (ct = i = 0, j = s.length(); i < j; i++) {
            _c = s.charAt(i);
            ct += (_c == c) ? 1 : 0;
        }

        return ct;
    }
```

to count the number of semicolons in your string.

Managing the delimiter character is the key to solving the problem.